# emberjs analogue of rails partial

Tags: ember.js

I am porting my rails view to emberjs. It seems that there are view and outlet helper for template separation. Since outlet is for state change, I am planning to use view helper to mimic rails partial. Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declaring views just to use them as partials is probably overkill. What might suit you best is the `{{template}}` helper in handlebars. If you've got a precompiled template in your Ember.TEMPLATES hash, you can do `{{template "sometemplate"}}` to inject that template, similar to a rails partial.

There's also a syntax particularly for partials in vanilla Handlebars, but I don't think it's well supported in Emberland and I never see anyone use it, and template does the same thing afaik.

### Update 1/19/2013

There is now a [{{partial}} helper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/015138ea569725811b43e0fd851dfd0c08446890#packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/template.js) you can use to insert insert template partials, whose filename's (and therefore `Ember.TEMPLATES` names) must begin with an underscore. Thanks to @brg for the heads up.

Comment: I felt the need to add this update for those who will run into this answer in the future. **{{partial}} helper** has now been added to emberjs which gives a rails like partial functionality, therefore,  **{{template}} helper** will no longer work in the future. Like rails, you have to use a leading underscore in your partial template's name.

Here is the actual commit: **[Add {{partial}}](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/015138ea569725811b43e0fd851dfd0c08446890#packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/template.js)**